# Rotation of galaxies and gravitomagnetism

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, dark-matter, galaxies, galaxy-rotation-curve

Can we explain the bigger speed of rotation of the galaxies from gravitomagnetic field acting from the "inner layers" of the galaxy to the "outer layers" of the galaxy?

Comment: "bigger speed of rotation" -- Bigger than what?

Comment: I believe this paper is related to the question: https://doi.org/10.1140/epjc/s10052-021-08967-3

Comment: bigger speed than the one we calculate using only the gravity of all the stars in the Milky Way

Comment: but it is just a theory correct?if we dont find any WIMP (dark matter candidate) can we say for sure it is due to gravitomagnetism?

Comment: If we dont find any WIMP, there are an ocean of other theories that may possibly explain rotation of galaxies. Disproving A does not prove B. There is currently much more evidence and work supporting the WIMP model, which is only 1 candidate for dark matter. Scientific consensus would currently answer your question with "no, that is due to dark matter, and we would expect gravitomagnetism to have a (v/c)^2 tiny effect." A single paper or a handful of papers are usually wrong, because each individual paper may contain glaring errors. This is why consensus is necessary.